# Swift vs. +[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]

Tags: objective-c, swift, foundation, nsvalue

In Objective-C, I might use `+[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` to keep a unique ID of an object, where I don't wish to retain the object itself. Seems like that's deprecated for Swift.

How to do in Swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's still there. It's just been adjusted to be one of `NSValue`'s initializers:

```
let anObject = "Hello!"
let value = NSValue(nonretainedObject: anObject)
```

Comment: Doh. Gotta think more Swifty.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
let foo: NSString = "hello"
let fooval: NSValue = NSValue(nonretainedObject: foo)

fooval.description // evaluates to "<5040d191 b87f0000>", address of `foo`
```